# how can i always rewind my code and run it in Javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a counter. When the counter comes to the end, I want to rewind it. So I'm trying to get it into a continuous while loop. How can I do that?

my code:

```
const app = Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      textRed: "text-danger bg-white",
      counter: 0,
    };
  },
  created() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.counter++;
    }, 1000);
  },
  computed: {
    boxClass() {
      return {
        "text-success": this.counter === 0,
        "text-warning": this.counter === 1,
        "text-info": this.counter === 2,
        "text-primary": this.counter === 3,
        "text-danger": this.counter === 4,
      };
    },
  },
}).mount("#app");
```

Comment: What have you tried? It shouldn't be difficult to check the counter value and act accordingly.

Comment: I don't want to do it with an if loop how can it be written in a cleaner way

Answer (score 0):

You could use the remainder operator, and a generic array like this:

```js
Vue.createApp({
  data() {
    return {
      textRed: "text-danger bg-white",
      counter: 0,
      classes: [
        "text-success",
        "text-warning",
        "text-info",
        "text-primary",
        "text-danger"
      ]
    };
  },
  created() {
    setInterval(() => {
      this.counter++;
    }, 1000);
  },
  computed: {
    boxClass() {
      return this.classes[this.counter % this.classes.length]
    },
  },
}).mount("#app");
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@3"></script>
<div id="app">{{boxClass}}</div>
```